# Directly refer to a public synonym in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, schema, synonym

I know this is backwards, but say we have an inflexible tool or situation which always creates SELECT statements in the form

```
SELECT * FROM ${SCHEMA}.${TABLE};
```

Now say we have a public synonym for table called MY_TABLE but no actual MY_TABLE in the current schema. That is our user is USER but the synonym for MY_TABLE points to OTHER_USER.MY_TABLE.

Note that this works fine as expected: select * from MY_TABLE UNION ALL select * from OTHER_USER.MY_TABLE;

I'd like to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM SYNONYMS.${TABLE};
```

Is there anything we can place in ${SCHEMA} that will force Oracle to find and resolve the synonym? I've tried the following *literal* SQL statements to try to refer to the synonym directly and they don't work.

```
select count(*) from USER.MY_TABLE; 

select count(*) from CURRENT_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE;

select count(*) from .MY_TABLE;

select count(*) from %.MY_TABLE;
```

Note that we must refer to the synonym because we change the synonym frequently to help with production installs therefore I can't just place OTHER_USER in $SCHEMA because it could be OTHER_USER or OTHER_USER2 or OTHER_USER3 for reasons outside of the control of my code.

Comment: Is `USER` in the question the `USER` function, or an actual username - if the latter can you make it, say, `USERA` in the question to avoid the ambiguity?

Comment: Yes. its because my code HAS to have something in this case. Its a silly situation to be in but placing SOMETHING there in this case would be the easiest/best way to handle the inflexible tool. However, 'select count(*) from SYS.MY_TABLE;' did not work :( 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'

Comment: Mmm, yes, I should have checked; you can describe a table like that but not select from it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the synonym owner `PUBLIC` as the reference schema; as `USERA`:

```
create table t42 (id number);
create public synonym t42 for t42;
grant select on t42 to userb;
```

Then as `USERB`:

```
select * from "PUBLIC"."T42";

no rows selected
```

But it seems like the 'schema' has to be quoted:

```
select * from public.t42;
select * from public.t42
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name


select * from "PUBLIC".t42;

no rows selected
```

Which may or may not be possible for you. If you can make `${SCHEMA}` equals `"PUBLIC"`, with the double-quotes, then it may solve your problem.

I'm not sure why this has to be quoted, upper-case identifiers usually don't; but then `PUBLIC` isn't a normal user, so maybe it shouldn't be surprising that it needs special handling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your underlying motivation, but as I see it you may consider using a dedicated user schema and creating views within that schema that refer to the eventual object. Views can be used as symbolic links.

Why can't:

```
 select count(*) from USER.MY_TABLE;
```

refer to a view in USER's schema named MY_TABLE that refers to whatever table is currently needed. You can recreate the view instead of repointing a synonym.

```
create view USER.MY_TABLE
   as select * from OTHER_USER.MY_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be a literal value we can use for ${SCHEMA}. However, we do have the flexibility to find the schema owner this way, save the value, then use that value in ${SCHEMA}.

```
select TABLE_OWNER from all_synonyms where TABLE_NAME='MY_TABLE' and OWNER='PUBLIC';
```

This query properly returns OTHER_USER, which we can then use.